# How can I model an object that has a plain array of strings with ember data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

How can I model an object that has a plain array of strings? 
If I do the following it shows me the emails but when modifying their value they are not updated.

The server sends/receives the following data:

```
"data":
[
    {
        "attributes" : {
            "id":1,
            "name":"Jhon",
            "emails":["jhon@gmail.com","jhon@other.com"]},
            "relationships": (,..}
        }
    }

    ...
```

Model:

```
export default Model.extend({
  id: attr('string'),
  name: attr('string'),
  emails: attr()
})
```

Template:

```
{{#each model.emails as |email|}}
    <input type="text" value={{email}}>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Does your `emails` contains two values only?

Comment: No, that was an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as email is a list  in your above json, so it is better to make your object design with one to many relationship as below:-
here 2 objects are there 1]employee 2]emailList

```
app/models/employee.js


import DS from 'ember-data';
export default Model.extend({
 id: DS.attr('string'),
 name: DS.attr('string'),
 emails: DS.hasMany('email-list'),
})

app/models/email-list.js

import DS from 'ember-data';
export default Model.extend({
 email: DS.attr('string'),
 employee: DS.belongsTo('employee')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be enough:

```
export default Model.extend({
  id: attr('string'),
  name: attr('string'),
  emails: attr()
})
```